# error in receiving data from interfaces through raw sockets

Tags: python, interface, raw-sockets

I have given my program below. Here I want to receive data from simhost interface through raw sockets. Then I want to write it into a buffer, but as soon as select call happens program execution stops and shows keyboard interrupt. What is the problem with my program?

```
import socket
import select
import sys
import time
from socket import socket, AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW

s = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW)
s.bind(("simhost-eth2", 0))
buffer = []
input = [s]
while 1:
    inputready, outputready, exceptready = select.select(input, [], [])
    for s in inputready:
        l, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
        buffer.append(l)
        print buffer
```